# multiple choice quiz in javascript using arrays

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a multiple choice state capitals quiz in javascript. I have an array of all 50 states (stateArray) and an array of all 50 capitals (capitalArray) in the correct order. 
I have a table with the question "What is the capital of (blank)" and I want (blank) to be populated with a state from the stateArray.
 I then have 4 radio buttons where I want one populated with the correct answer from the capitalArray and the other 3 populated with random capitals from the capitalArray. How do I do this?
I've been looking all over the internet for the answer, but I can't seem to find it. I know how to code the question/radio buttons if I were to type in the text I wanted displayed next to each one, but I don't know how to get it to pull from the arrays. Please help.

EDIT: Ok, maybe I asked this the wrong way. I don't want someone to do my homework for me. There is much more to the assignment, I just can't figure out how to do this one part of it - specifically pulling the data from the arrays to populate the question and radio buttons. I can't find the information in my text book or on the internet. I'm just frustrated and confused at this point and I don't know where to go for help. If someone knows WHERE I can find a tutorial or info on how to do this, that would help too.

To whomever marked down my question: If you're going to mark it down, it would be immensely helpful if you would leave a comment telling me why so I can improve my future questions. Thank you! :-)

Comment: You do realise that if you programmed this, it would take me all of five minutes to write a program that automatically gives me a perfect score, right? This kind of thing should be done server-side, and the only thing sent to the user should be the question and four answers. The user then submits their answer and the server checks to see if it is correct and responds accordingly.

Comment: Its helpful to tell us what you have tried already and provide any relevant code you have. The questions asked on SO are mainly aimed at fixing a part of the code that isn't working, not getting someone to write the code for you.

Comment: You're basically asking people to do your homework...

Comment: The downvote isn't mine, but this is very broad and more a project description than a specific question. Your best bet might be looking at jQuery which makes dynamic generation of elements trivial. (Kolink's advice still applies, though, of course)

Comment: I'm not asking for someone to write the whole thing for me - I can do my own homework. I just want to know how to get the question and the radio buttons to pull from the arrays. That's where I am stuck. I will write the rest of the code myself. I don't have any code to submit yet, because I'm trying to figure this step out. Perhaps the better question to ask is: Does anyone know where I should look to figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to get it to pull from the arrays

For every row in your table pick a random index from any array (e.g. states):

```
var questionIndex = Math.round(Math.random(stateArray.length));
```

Then use the obtained question index to get the values from both arrays provided that both are in correct order:

```
var question = stateArray[questionIndex],
    answer = capitalArray[questionIndex];
```

You can now populate the HTML fields of your row.

**Edit:**

To get the "incorrect" answers for your radio buttons you can simply:

```
var incorrectAnswerIndices = [],
    incorrectAnswerIndex;

while (incorrectAnswerIndices.length < 3) {
    incorrectAnswerIndex = Math.round(Math.random(stateArray.length));
    // Check for collisions with the correct answer,
    // and make sure there are no identical answers:
    if (incorrectAnswerIndex !== questionIndex &&
            incorrectAnswerIndices.indexOf(incorrectAnswerIndex) === -1) {
        incorrectAnswerIndices.push(incorrectAnswerIndex);
    }
}
```

You can now iterate `incorrectAnswerIndices` array and create/populate values of your false question radio buttons with values, e.g.: `capitalArray[incorrectAnswerIndices[0]]` which is the first of three incorrect capital names for the given state.